# how to pass value from servlet to jsp

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a servlet dispatcher

when I using anyway to pass value I always failed.

this's my error message

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    servlet.checkServlet.doPost(checkServlet.java:19)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.notifyAttributeAssigned(Request.java:1489)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1475)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setAttribute(RequestFacade.java:539)
    servlet.checkServlet.doPost(checkServlet.java:18)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    servlet.checkServlet.doPost(checkServlet.java:19)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>checkServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>checkServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>checkServlet</servlet-name>
          <http-method>Get</http-method>
          <http-method>Post</http-method>
        <url-pattern>/checkview.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

servlet.java

```
public class checkServlet extends HttpServlet {
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    request.setAttribute("books", "book1"); 
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/checkview.jsp") .include(request,response); 
    }
}
```

finally is my jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<% String msg = (String)request.getAttribute("book"); %>
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
form servlet： <%= msg %>
</body>
</html>
```

have anyone can teach me how to fix and why have the problem?

Comment: You mapping your Servlet to  <url-pattern>/checkview.jsp</url-pattern> and including itself and including itself and including itself .... that overfows the stack.

Comment: use `request.getRequestDispatcher("/checkview.jsp").forward(request, response);`
instead of `request.getRequestDispatcher("/checkview.jsp") .include(request,response); `

Comment: Furthermore, in your JSP page, you have to get the attribute `books`.

Comment: Change url-pattern to `<url-pattern>/checkview</url-pattern>`